# How to show total number of emails in my gmail in google sheets cell

Tags: gmail-api

I want to show the total number of emails in my gmail (not unread emails) total number of emails. I want to show the number in one of my Google sheets cells.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the `messagesTotal` property of [Users: getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile). This property gets the total number of messages in the mailbox.

HTTP request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/profile
```

Response

```
{
  "emailAddress": string,
  "messagesTotal": integer,
  "threadsTotal": integer,
  "historyId": unsigned long
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I've tried to know the total number of emails I have is: opened my Gmail in a web browser, then just above the section that lists the first (50 or 100) mails, there's a checkbox. Clicking it will select all the emails on the current page.
A message appears below the checkbox section saying `All 50 conversations on this page are selected. Select all {{number}} conversations in primary.` Now that {{number}} is the number of all the emails (read & unread) in your `primary` inbox. Do same for `social` and `promotions` tabs and add them up.
That's it if that's what you are asking.